# How to retrieve rows that do not exist in a table?

Tags: mysql, select

I want to retrieve rows that both exist and do not exist in a table by a combination of several joins. I have the next query:

```
SELECT S.Id_Sesion, S.Id_Usuario, S.Id_Video, S.Avance
FROM    sesiones AS S, grupos AS G, grupos_det AS GD
WHERE   G.idgrupos = '000001'
AND     G.idgrupos = GD.idgrupos
AND     GD.Id_Usuario = S.Id_Usuario
AND     S.Id_Sesion = (SELECT MAX(S2.Id_Sesion) 
            FROM sesiones AS S2 
            WHERE S2.Id_Usuario = S.Id_Usuario
            AND S2.Id_Video = S.Id_Video)
ORDER BY S.Id_Usuario, S.Id_Video
```

And it returns values such as

```
30  1   1   10
34  1   3   40
64  1   5   95
```

Those are the results that do appear on the table, but I need to retrieve data that do not exist, example:

```
0 or null   1   2   0
0 or null   1   4   0
0 or null   1   6   0
```

Where 2, 4, and 6 are the id of videos that do exist in Videos Table but the user hasn't seen yet. Thank you.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is your best friend here. Also don't you old styles join (comma separated table in from clause) use inner/left join clauses instead

Comment: you could put your query in the place of QUERY in the following: `SELECT C.* FROM videos AS V LEFT JOIN (QUERY) as C ON (C.Id_Video=V.Id)` ... assuming your table with videos is `videos` and the fields match as i describe.

Comment: @JorgeCampos before I posted this, i tried the Left Join with several combinations of my tables and none worked. Am i getting something wrong? I don't know. I thought that because all the records exist in all the tables, the left join is not working for me. Because as i said, some records exist, it is a combination of id/keys that is not working for me.

Comment: @Jakumi Thank you but it didn't work. Keeps retrieving the same records. I hope you could give me some other idea.